# Xcode 4.2 iOS5 Storyboard reference is nil while trying to implement Page View Controller

Tags: objective-c, storyboard, ios5, xcode4.2

While trying to implement the Default Page Based app in another Single View application, I tried everything, but `self.storyboard` in the class that extends UIViewController is always `nil`.

Is there any tutorial I can follow?

- Storyboard has the following: Login Screen (UIViewController) -> UITabBarController -> UITableViewController; on `didSelectCell…` I added 2 UIPageViewController that are identical to the ones in the page passed to the app, and the ModelController.h/m and did all the alterations needed to my knowledge.
- `self.storyboard` in the RootViewController.m is always `nil`, and it ends up crashing my app.

P.S. I am a beginner, and I don't know how to get a reference of the storyboard object from my ViewController.m/h to the RootViewController.m/h.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not too sure what you are trying to get at, but just use this project http://www.wannabegeek.com/?p=168

at the bottom of the page there is a github link which will allow you to download the whole project, no coding necessary.

and here's the github link just incase you couldn't see it

https://github.com/wannabegeek/PageViewController